# Executing a command inside a running LXC

Tags: linux, lxc

I want to execute a command inside an existing lxc without going through the regular Linux init. `lxc-execute` command is for that I guess but I get the following error when I run this command on my existing test lxc.

```
sudo lxc-execute -n test -- service apache2 start
```

I get following error:

```
lxc-execute: Failed to find an lxc-init
lxc-execute: invalid sequence number 1. expected 4
lxc-execute: failed to spawn 'test'
```

Answer (score 21):

Have you tried [`lxc-attach`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lxc-attach) instead? According the documentation,

> lxc-attach - start a process inside a running container.

Example to list all folders inside `home` of the container

```
lxc-attach -n myContainer -- ls -lh /home
```

If no process is defined, it creates a new shell inside the container.

Comment: The thing with `lxc-attach` is that you can't use it with `less`, e.g. `lxc-attach -n c1 -- dmesg | less`. The output is similar to what you get with `docker-compose exec ... | less` unless you pass `-T`.

Answer (score 1):

`lxc-execute` is designed to create and run and lxc container and execute the command. So it can not be used to execute a command currently setup and started one.

Quotation from Serge E. Hallyn @ https://www.mail-archive.com/lxc-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00134.html

> Moving an existing process into an existing, populated namespace will
>   likely never be possible.

You may try Ullrich Horlacher's lxc command but currently the page is out of order. Process is described in this post:

https://www.mail-archive.com/lxc-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg01970.html